# Diy programmable macro for USB via Arduino passthrough

Tags: arduino, keyboard, mouse, hid

I have a Logitech mouse which [allows programming macros](https://www.logitechg.com/en-us/innovation/g-hub.html), but it has a few missing features that I am after. Features I'm looking for:

- Cross-platform
- Easily change macros and their bindings without flashing new firmware

Here are the alternatives that I have found in my research so far:

1) ['AutoHotKey'](https://www.autohotkey.com/) for Windows and ['AutoKey'](https://github.com/autokey/autokey) for Linux. The problem here is that I could not find conclusive evidence that it will function with all games on my PC, while not triggering bans from anti-cheat engines like 'VAC' and 'Easy Anti-Cheat'. People use 'AutoHotKey' to make bot scripts to fire when their cursor passes over an enemy, so it might be banned outright by anti-cheat engines.

2) Add support for keyboards and mice for ['GIMX'](https://github.com/matlo/GIMX) software stack. 'GIMX' already has code established for intercepting user input and applying macros, so I could use my existing 'GIMX' setup for my PS3 instead - like this:

```
keyboard and mouse --> RPi --> 'GIMX' adapter --> PC.
```

3) Finally, use micro-controllers and USB host shields to connect each USB peripheral to a slave MCU which communicate to a master MCU. The slave MCU units would translate device specific macros triggers (e.g. remap extra mouse buttons to a number key for FPS weapons or a keyboard combination). The master MCU would handle macros triggered by both keyboard and mouse before finally passing it on via built-in USB serial CDC to my PC.

```
keyboard --> USB host shield --> slave mcu --|
                                         master mcu
mouse    --> USB host shield --> slave mcu --|
```

Looking at [this example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wTbjmulNSlw) ([source code](https://github.com/BlitzCityDIY/arduinoMacroKeyboard)), maybe I could just use Arduino's serial API for the master MCU? Also, how might I enable the three Arduino compatible MCUs to communicate without causing game impacting lag? Perhaps SPI?
I would like to go the hardware route, using either method two or three. Preferably three. However, I do not know how I would go about implementing method three. I do not know how USB communication works, so I cannot roll my own library - but I do know how to write in C++. So, if anyone could point me to some resources and Arduino libraries that would be great.

Possible Arduino libraries:

- Keyboard
- Arduino HID project https://github.com/NicoHood/HID
- USB Host Shield Library 2.0 https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0

**Edit 0:**

- Found a simple USB relay online which captures and sends USB packets via a Bluetooth module. I will study it to figure out how it works, and how I could add programmable macro capabilities.

  - github.com/juancgarcia/HID-Relay
- To fulfill my requirement to have macro profiles stored on the master MCU, I will reserve a special hex code for a PC to signal the relay software to store configuration data in EEPROM.